# Magit extremely slow in Windows. How do I optimize?

Tags: magit, microsoft-windows, git, performance

I am forced to use Windows 10 for a project. Yes, I would rather use GNU/Linux. To keep my sanity, I've tried to regard Windows as a bootloader for Emacs :)

Unfortunately, Magit (one of my favorite parts of Emacs, which also makes up for the lack of a good command line on Windows) is unbearably slow. I have an SSD, 16 GB of RAM and a quad-core i7 but it takes **eight seconds** to execute `magit-status` on a small repository. Then, when I want to stage another change, it takes about 5 seconds *per file*.

Here's what I've tried:

- `$ git config --global core.preloadindex true`
- `$ git config --global core.fscache true`
- `$ git config --global gc.auto 256`
- Adding the entire project to the Windows Defender (my only AV) exclusion list
- Setting the `magit-git-executable` to the regular msysgit one I downloaded (https://git-for-windows.github.io/). I checked and `git status` here takes < 1 second. I know that `magit-status` does way more, but this is too much.

Can anyone suggest ways to make this faster? I can't imagine anyone using Magit on Windows like this.

It was suggested that [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17783/why-does-emacs-take-longer-to-start-on-windows-than-on-linux) is a duplicate, but they asked:

> I'm struggling to understand why Emacs have noticeably shorter startup time on Ubuntu than Windows. Anyone knows the answer?

I know at least some reasons why Emacs, Git, and Magit are slower on Windows. I am asking *how do I optimize Magit* to do fewer things, or cache results, or something, even if it's at the expense of functionality.

Comment: `git-status` takes <1 second? It should be essentially instantaneous. Is there any perceptible delay at all?

Comment: Do you have the same issues running the equivalent `git` commands from the command line?

Comment: I think magit's default choice for `magit-git-executable` will probably be a bit faster (the ones in `cmd` and `bin` are actually wrappers, if `executable-find` returns one of them magit will attempt to set `magit-git-executable` to the "real" git). 8 seconds for a small repository sounds like something else is wrong though, takes ~0.8s for magit's repo here (Windows 8).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Emacs take longer to start on Windows than on Linux?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17783/why-does-emacs-take-longer-to-start-on-windows-than-on-linux)

Comment: See my answer on the above question. I think you're out of luck. Magit runs quite a few git commands in the status buffer, and while they're near instant on Linux, Windows makes things very slow.

Comment: Also, for a more accurate time, you could set `magit-refresh-verbose` to `t`.

Comment: @PythonNut I should have said instantaneous.

Comment: @elethan it's hard to find an exactly list of what it's doing, but no, it seems fast. I will try to investigate more.

Comment: "optimize Magit to do fewer things...even if it's at the expense of functionality." - Have you tried the suggestions listed under [Performance](http://magit.vc/manual/magit/Performance.html) in the manual?

Comment: Are you in a position to host a Linux VM in Windows? I found using Cygwin's X server with a non-desktop Linux distro (such as Ubuntu Server) was [an entirely agreeable workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3049375) when I had a Windows desktop.

Comment: @phils Unfortunately I can't install that (the powers that be have lots of rules). I would definitely have done that otherwise. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have actually done rather a lot of research on this and fundamentally the problem is that git for windows **sucks**

This is the upstream bug: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/596 and it requires somebody to rewrite shell scripts in C so that there is no more command forking. For me, its the interactive rebase that is the real killer (I can kick off an interactive rebase, go make tea, come back, read some news, drink the tea, and then **maybe** it's finished. It's much worse than a lot of people think it is), but general status-like calls are also enough to interrupt the work stride.

An alternative might be to update jGit to support the commands that magit uses, and then run it in nailgun to reduce the JVM startup time, I started a thread to discuss this: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jgit-dev/msg03064.html

You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485059 for some potential speedups, but honestly you'll barely notice them.

Something you can do in magit is to follow the author's advice in setting up a minimal `magit-status` just for staging

```el
;; WORKAROUND https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2395
(define-derived-mode magit-staging-mode magit-status-mode "Magit staging"
  "Mode for showing staged and unstaged changes."
  :group 'magit-status)
(defun magit-staging-refresh-buffer ()
  (magit-insert-section (status)
    (magit-insert-untracked-files)
    (magit-insert-unstaged-changes)
    (magit-insert-staged-changes)))
(defun magit-staging ()
  (interactive)
  (magit-mode-setup #'magit-staging-mode))
```

so, do you know any experienced C or Java developers who'd be able to help with either of the solutions to fix git or jGit?

Comment: I'm not so sure the problem is shell scripts vs. C, because `magit-status` takes a really long time as well, and I don't think status uses many of the shell scripts.

Comment: And thank you for that "minimal" `magit-status` code, it seem to help me a bit (it cuts my `magit-refresh` time down to 2-3 seconds).

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @Hut8 how fast is magit staging for you with the minimal code?

Comment: yup, `magit-staging` takes a couple of seconds for me too. Enough to interrupt my thinking, but not enough to destroy my day.

Comment: the reason why `magit-status` is slow is because it calls out to `git` maybe 10 or 20 times. Starting new processes on Windows is extremely slow compared to GNU platforms. The shell scripts are an extreme case of this (because pretty much every statement is a new process)

Answer (score 2):

Having recently looked at the a list of `call-process` calls from `magit-status` for another reason, it occured to me that some of them can be cached.  With the following advice `magit-status` on Magit's repo goes from 1.9 to 1.3 seconds (my previous measurement of 0.8s mentioned in the comments was for a different (faster) computer).  If you are already using `magit-staging` from the other answer it's probably not going to help much: I saw a reduction from 0.16 to 0.12 seconds (but that's barely larger than measurement noise).

### WARNING: This doesn't take care of updating the cache, so things may go wrong (especially if you are fiddling with your git configuration).

```el
(defvar-local magit-git--git-dir-cache nil)
(defvar-local magit-git--toplevel-cache nil)
(defvar-local magit-git--cdup-cache nil)

(defun memoize-rev-parse (fun &rest args)
  (pcase (car args)
    ("--git-dir"
     (unless magit-git--git-dir-cache
       (setq magit-git--git-dir-cache (apply fun args)))
     magit-git--git-dir-cache)
    ("--show-toplevel"
     (unless magit-git--toplevel-cache
       (setq magit-git--toplevel-cache (apply fun args)))
     magit-git--toplevel-cache)
    ("--show-cdup"
     (let ((cdup (assoc default-directory magit-git--cdup-cache)))
       (unless cdup
         (setq cdup (cons default-directory (apply fun args)))
         (push cdup magit-git--cdup-cache))
       (cdr cdup)))
    (_ (apply fun args))))

(advice-add 'magit-rev-parse-safe :around #'memoize-rev-parse)

(defvar-local magit-git--config-cache (make-hash-table :test 'equal))

(defun memoize-git-config (fun &rest keys)
  (let ((val (gethash keys magit-git--config-cache :nil)))
    (when (eq val :nil)
      (setq val (puthash keys (apply fun keys) magit-git--config-cache)))
    val))

(advice-add 'magit-get :around #'memoize-git-config)
(advice-add 'magit-get-boolean :around #'memoize-git-config)
```

Comment: why don't you just use the http://melpa.org/#/memoize package?

Comment: @fommil: I needed to memoize rev-parse per buffer for *some* args. I couldn't see a way to do so after a cursory look at the memoize package. Also it says it can't handle memoizing `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Use Emacs on [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).

I did an extensive use of magit when I worked on a Linux box.
But was kind of forced to use Windows 10.
I tried to use Magit though I couldn't stand how slow it was.
So I just switched to [SublimeMerge](https://www.sublimemerge.com/) for git use.
After one year using it, I haven't looked back.

But since I have tried native Emacs on Windows and Emacs on WSL...
Just made a test to check `magit-status` on same repo.
I manually started a stopwatch with a hotkey in Windows.
So there is a bit of time gap between when `magit-status` ends and when the watch stops.

In my case *Emacs-on-WSL* beats *Emacs-on-Windows* by ~2 secs vs ~6 secs.
Both tests made starting emacs with `emacs -Q`.

[image]

[image]